Why does DecimalFormat behave strangely for this specific example?
I observed some strange behavior when formatting doubles using Java's DecimalFormat.
// returns "0.1" as expected
(new DecimalFormat("0.#", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))).format(0.05); 

// returns "0.01" as expected
(new DecimalFormat("0.##", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))).format(0.005); 

 // returns "0", although I would expect it to return "0.001"
(new DecimalFormat("0.###", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))).format(0.0005);

// returns "0", although I would expect "0.0001"
(new DecimalFormat("0.####", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))).format(0.00005); 

Can anyone explain why the third and fourth statements return "0"?
Even more strangely:
// returns "1.105" as expected
(new DecimalFormat("#.###")).format(1.1045);

// returns "0.104" (why??)
(new DecimalFormat("#.###")).format(0.1045); 


Have you tried setting the format's rounding mode via .setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP)?

Also, please have a look at this question and answerOdd result From DecimalFormat Rounding Half Up

I thought it was because decimal numbers couldn't be precisely represented in binary; but, interestingly, System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.0005)) prints 0.0005000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875 which is greater than 0.0005 so I would have expected the DecimalFormat to round it up.

maybe using java.util.Formatter (or String.format()) will give better results

For your second set of numbers (1.1045 and 0.1045) the results are indeed as expected. Try println(new BigDecimal(0.1045)) to see why. (And read any of the many documents about floating point precision if you don't understand what's happening.) But for your first set of numbers (0.0005) the results are surprising.

@HovercraftFullOfEels: thanks for the links, but they did not help really. I do not understand whether this is a roundingMode issue (where both neighbors are equidistant), or whether the number is indeed closer to one of the neighbors.
in the second set of examples, I do not understand how one number can be closer to the greater number, while other being closer to the lesser one. And setting roundingMode did not help either, so I do not think the numbers are equidistant to both numbers

Setting rounding mode to HALF_UP does indeed make it 0.001.

This is not a duplicate of "Odd result From DecimalFormat Rounding Half Up". This particular question is not about an odd result when rounding half up. In fact, if you round half up, with 0.0005, you get the expected result. But when using the default rounding (which is half even) you would expect 0.001 but you get 0 instead. This cannot be explained by how 0.0005 comes out as a double, which is actually slightly higher than 0.0005 so you'd expect rounding to 0.001.

the second set of examples are due to the rounding mode. But I cannot really understand why (with the default roundind mode), 0.0005 gets truncated and formatted as 0, while 0.0015 gets formatted as 0.002 and 0.0025 gets formatted as 0.003

According to the HALF_EVEN rule, 0.0005 should round to 0, because that's what rounding towards an even digit means. But what is puzzling is why 0.005 rounds to 0.01. The behaviour is inconsistent. Either they should both round towards 1 (because 0.005 and 0.0005 are not representable precisely with binary floating point - they are both slightly higher than 0.005 and 0.0005 respectively) or they should both round to 0.
